# How to send emails using yahoo or gmail in c++

Tags: c++, email, gmail, yahoo

I wanna send an email in my c++ program, it seems little complex.  Is there way to use yahoo or gmail to use them to send my emails?

Answer (score 2):

A basic internet [search](http://www.vmime.org/) reveals the following:

1. [C++ SMTP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example)
2. [VMime a C++ Mail library](http://www.vmime.org/)
3. [libsmtp a C library to send mail via smtp](http://libsmtp.berlios.de/)

In short if you have a gmail or yahoo account you can use their SMTP server to send messages using either of the three links above to assist you in using SMTP.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the [SMTPClientSession](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SMTPClientSession.html) from the POCO library.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/managedc.aspx?cat=2) tutorial has everything you need, if you are working in a .net environment.